# Who said Web SQL [doesnt feel like Javascript]?

Tags: web-sql, indexeddb

I'm writing a report and can't remember where I read that. Their reason for switching to indexedDB

Answer (score 1):

The problem with WebSQL was which SQL dialect to use. Every browser would implement his own db in the backgroud with his own SQL dialect, and this would mean there is no standardisation. For more info about it read [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)

Comment: You can also take al took at the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596579/local-db-api-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative for more information

Answer (score 0):

WebSQL is deprecated. IndexedDB is the new standard, and of course, better in the spirit Javascript style and scalability.