# Local DB API - deprecated what is the alternative?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sqlite, indexeddb

The local DB api based on SQLite is going down. According to w3c it has to be replaced indexedDB. But IndexedDB API is still work in progress so no implementation yet.
For an app that needs massive db storage... and for the time being; what is the alternative? What would be the most future proof?

Local storage is no option as I need to store data structured (relational), and a lot of it.
Cloud based alternatives are also out of scope. I need something local.

Comment: which platforms do you target?

Comment: For the time being I would classify the importance of the platform as in: 1- iOS. 2- Android. 3- Windows Phone 7 (I mainly target tablets for all these vendors). Thx

Comment: I would say indexeddb is the way to go. IE, FF and chrome allready support it, but for mobile devices it's still a hell. I would advice you to stay with websql for now, I think phonegap will keep supporting it for a while.

Comment: w3c are really dumb... why the hell are they kicking websql anyway... SQL has always and is still best suited for data querying and relational dbs are and will always be best suited for data storage... man....

Comment: The problem with the spec was, that there isn't a standerd way to query. Every vendor used SQLite, but a spec can't be build on one product, that would be very dangerous. Also in most cases different db vendors mean different SQL dialects. This is also in contradiction with a standard way of working. This would mean you would have to check which db you are working and then use a different dialect. That is why they decided to use a uniform API called indexeddb

Comment: I do not know much about indexeddb but I have seen that it's json based hence there is no "dialiact" per say to query data. SQL is a standard, all they could have done is stick to it... or rather define a spec for an interface that links to the underlying db regardless what language it uses (simple example is odbc and/or jdbc)... not that hard if you look at it this way.

Comment: I can tell you that browsers use an database like SQL lite to store the data in only the interface to query is the indexeddb API, so in that way indexeddb is something like an odbc. Only it's very simple and slim. If you want to learn more about indexeddb take a look at my blog http://www.kristofdegrave.be I have several blogposts about it. http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/09/indexed-db-basics.html is a good one to start with. It explains the basics of indexeddb

Comment: Thanks kristof. Could you add an answer so I flag it :)

Comment: Tnx, added a concatination of my comments as awnser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say indexeddb is the way to go. IE, FF and chrome allready support it, but for mobile devices it's still a hell. I would advice you to stay with websql for now, I think phonegap will keep supporting it for a while.

The problem with the spec was, that there isn't a standerd way to query. Every vendor used SQLite, but a spec can't be build on one product, that would be very dangerous. Also in most cases different db vendors mean different SQL dialects. This is also in contradiction with a standard way of working. This would mean you would have to check which db you are working and then use a different dialect. That is why they decided to use a uniform API called indexeddb.

All browsers that use an database like SQL lite to store the data in only the interface to query is the indexeddb API, so in that way indexeddb is something like an odbc. Only it's very simple and slim. If you want to learn more about indexeddb take a look at my [blog](http://www.kristofdegrave.be) I have several blogposts about it. [This one](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/09/indexed-db-basics.html) is a good one to start with. It explains the basics of indexeddb.

Answer (score 0):

> Local storage is no option as I need to store data structured
>   (relational), and a lot of it

I asked similar questions in past, at some point I gave up trying to find a native solution. I end up with using [this plugin](https://github.com/chbrody/Cordova-SQLitePlugin).

The advantages are:

1. You will not be bounded by quota limit on iOS platform (~5Mb)
   when using WebSQL.
2. You are able distribute pre-populated databases. (I know there is
       a workaround for WebSQL as well, but it doesn't always work.)
3. You can encrypt your database. (I don't know if you ever need
           this)
4. There is no persistence problem as mentioned [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-330).

The disadvantages are:

1. There is no implementation for Windows yet. You might think of
   writing your own plugin for Windows.
2. With Phonegap 2.1, they started to support ARC on iOS platform. As
   far as I tested, the plugin does not support ARC at the moment. You
   will need to tweak it.

Comment: Thanks noway. Although what is ARC?

Comment: Automatic Reference Counting. It is the way how iOS deal with garbage collection. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

Comment: Also here is the workaround: http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/automatic-reference-counting-arc-and-cordova-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Why not try of [IndexedDB wrapper](https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/ydn-db) of my own open source library? It works both old and new standard of IndexedDB API as well as great fail back to WebSQL. The wrapper API is very IndexedDB API centric and plan to support every single feature.

Comment: I need a highly future proof alternative hence I cannot rely on third party libraries for such an important scope as storage. thanks

Comment: I see. IndexedDB is future proof, but currently in transition. BTW, If you use closure compiler, the code is no longer a third party.